# Watching variable to see if it changes value

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging my code to see if the variable is receiving new values during execution.
How can I watch it and make it stops when the value is changed by something?

I've got a CheckList and set the selectedValues with some values, and for some reason, the values selected are disappearing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the outline view (Window -> Show View -> Outline) to select your variable. Right-click it and select Toggle Watchpoint. It will create a breakpoint for your variable. Right-click this breakpoint, select properties and leave only the checkbox "Field modification" enabled.

I think that this cannot be done for variables declared inside methods, although you can use it for class or instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a breakpoint with a condition for the value.

Comment: where would he set the breakpoint, if he doesn't know where and when the value is changed?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a breakpoint on the setter method for the value.

Comment: what if the value is changed without the use of a setter? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the debugger does appear to help. esp if the problem doesn't appear when you debug it. You can add logging which can show you where a change is made. e.g.

```
log.info("Changed "+changeDescription, new Throwable("HERE"));
```